# How to convert the following grammar to LL(1)?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

The following grammar is given:

\begin{align*}
M &\rightarrow d M d \\
M &\rightarrow e M e \\
M &\rightarrow f M f \\
M &\rightarrow \varepsilon
\end{align*}

I've checked it with the LL(1) table and there are ambiguous cell entries.

Now, I've tried to convert it to LL(1), but without success. Is this not possible for this grammar? Why?

Comment: Have you tried removing left recursion and left-factoring the grammar?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no left recursion. Left-factorizing the grammar will break up the grammar, because, as shown above, it always produces 2 non-terminals.

Comment: Good, you're right about left-recursion. Sometimes you need to add/modify production rules of your grammar to convert to LL(1), and left-factoring is definitely required in your case to get closer to a more useful result.

Comment: This generates the language of palindromes with character d, e, f, which I believe to be LL(*). Consider the case where you have a string consisting only of d's. To choose the right production you need to know if the d is the left one or the right one. To know that, you have to know the length of the string, which requires arbitrary lookahead.